# Uncaught TypeError cannot read property 'classlist' of null

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I keep reading the other possible duplicates of this question but I still don't find the solution needed for me to finish this. So, I downloaded a CSS File that contains a Hamburger for all widths, however their class names conflicted with Bootstrap's Nav classes, so I changed the SCSS file and CSS to make it work, then changing also the names in the .js file to avoid errors.

However, it seems like the error is still here and won't go away . This time, the menu list is hidden in the hamburger, however the hamburger is not working. Here's the code for all things affected.

```js
(function() {

 var hamburger = {
  naviToggle: document.querySelector('.navi-toggle'),
  navi: document.querySelector('navi'),

  doToggle: function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   this.naviToggle.classList.toggle('expanded');
   this.navi.classList.toggle('expanded');
  }
 };

 hamburger.naviToggle.addEventListener('click', function(e) { hamburger.doToggle(e); });

}());
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro");
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -moz-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; }
  *:focus {
    outline: none; }

html {
  background: #5634d1;
  color: white;
  font: normal 10px/1.42857 "Source Sans Pro", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }

body {
  background: none;
  color: inherit;
  font: inherit; }

a {
  color: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none; }
  a:hover {
    opacity: 0.8; }

/* nav toggle */
.navi-toggle {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 2rem;
  left: 2rem;
  position: fixed;
  top: 2rem;
  width: 3.6rem;
  z-index: 2; }
  .navi-toggle:hover {
    opacity: 0.8; }
  .navi-toggle .navi-toggle-bar,
  .navi-toggle .navi-toggle-bar::after,
  .navi-toggle .navi-toggle-bar::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    background: white;
    content: '';
    height: 0.4rem;
    width: 100%; }
  .navi-toggle .navi-toggle-bar {
    margin-top: 0; }
  .navi-toggle .navi-toggle-bar::after {
    margin-top: 0.8rem; }
  .navi-toggle .navi-toggle-bar::before {
    margin-top: -0.8rem; }
  .navi-toggle.expanded .navi-toggle-bar {
    background: transparent; }
  .navi-toggle.expanded .navi-toggle-bar::after, .navi-toggle.expanded .navi-toggle-bar::before {
    background: white;
    margin-top: 0; }
  .navi-toggle.expanded .navi-toggle-bar::after {
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg); }
  .navi-toggle.expanded .navi-toggle-bar::before {
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg); }

/* nav */
.navi {
  -webkit-transition: left 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: left 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: left 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: left 0.5s ease;
  transition: left 0.5s ease;
  background: #28dde0;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 2rem;
  height: 100vh;
  right: -30rem;
  padding: 6rem 2rem 2rem 2rem;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 20rem;
  z-index: 1; }
  .navi.expanded {
    left: 0; }
  .navi ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; }

/*# sourceMappingURL=nav.css.map */


/* NAVIGATION MENU */

div#main-menu {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
.btn-link {
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #007bff;
    background-color: transparent;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0;
}
ul.dropdown-list-item {
    padding: 0;
}
ul.dropdown-list-item li {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 100%;
}
ul.dropdown-list-item li a {
    font-size: 1rem;
}
.btn-link:hover{
  color: #fff;
}
/***  NAVIGATION ICONS   ***/
button.user-icon {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
}
.nav-icons {
    position: absolute;
    right: 13%;
    top: 23%;
}
/***  END NAVIGATION ICONS   ***/
```

```html
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<nav class="navi">

  <div id="main-menu">
    <div class="main-menu-list">
      <div class="main-menu-header" id="main-menu-one">
        <h5 class="mb-0">
          <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#dropdown-list-one" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="main-menu">Mens</button>
        </h5>
      </div>
      <div id="dropdown-list-one" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="main-menu-one" data-parent="#main-menu">
        <div class="dropdown-list-body">
          <ul class="dropdown-list-item">
            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

      <div class="main-menu-list">
        <div class="main-menu-header" id="main-menu-one">
          <h5 class="mb-0">
            <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#dropdown-list-two" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="main-menu">Womens</button>
          </h5>
        </div>
        <div id="dropdown-list-two" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="main-menu-one" data-parent="#main-menu">
          <div class="dropdown-list-body">
            <ul class="dropdown-list-item">
              <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

        <div class="main-menu-list">
          <div class="main-menu-header" id="main-menu-one">
            <h5 class="mb-0">
              <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#dropdown-list-three" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="main-menu">Accessories</button>
            </h5>
          </div>
          <div id="dropdown-list-three" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="main-menu-one" data-parent="#main-menu">
            <div class="dropdown-list-body">
              <ul class="dropdown-list-item">
                <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          </div>

          <div class="main-menu-list">
            <div class="main-menu-header" id="main-menu-one">
              <h5 class="mb-0">
                <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#dropdown-list-four" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="main-menu">Equipments</button>
              </h5>
            </div>
            <div id="dropdown-list-four" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="main-menu-one" data-parent="#main-menu">
              <div class="dropdown-list-body">
                <ul class="dropdown-list-item">
                  <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="main-menu-list">
              <div class="main-menu-header" id="main-menu-one">
                <h5 class="mb-0">
                  <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#dropdown-list-five" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="main-menu">More</button>
                </h5>
              </div>
              <div id="dropdown-list-five" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="main-menu-one" data-parent="#main-menu">
                <div class="dropdown-list-body">
                  <ul class="dropdown-list-item">
                    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
          </nav>
    
          <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-default fixed-top" id="nav">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="navi-toggle">
                <div class="navi-toggle-bar"></div>
              </div>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php"><img src="img/logo.png"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="container nav-icons">
             <button type="button" class="iconton">
              <img src="img/cart-product-white.png" alt="">
            </button> 
            <button type="button" class="iconton" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#userSearch" id="icon-search">
              <img src="img/navbar-icon.png">
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="iconton" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#userSign" id="icon-user">
              <img src="img/user.png">
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="container">

          </div>
        </nav>
```

If someone can solve this, it would be great! Thanks!

Comment: Missing dot character `.` which reflects class within selector string, `document.querySelector('navi')` should be `document.querySelector('.navi')`

Comment: oh man, that was so sloppy of mine... thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
navi: document.querySelector('navi')
```

should be

```js
navi: document.querySelector('.navi')
```

as it is a class.

```js
(function() {

    var hamburger = {
        naviToggle: document.querySelector('.navi-toggle'),
        navi: document.querySelector('.navi'),

        doToggle: function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            this.naviToggle.classList.toggle('expanded');
            this.navi.classList.toggle('expanded');
        }
    };

    hamburger.naviToggle.addEventListener('click', function(e) { hamburger.doToggle(e); });

}());
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro");
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -moz-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; }
  *:focus {
    outline: none; }

html {
  background: #5634d1;
  color: white;
  font: normal 10px/1.42857 "Source Sans Pro", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }

body {
  background: none;
  color: inherit;
  font: inherit; }

a {
  color: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none; }
  a:hover {
    opacity: 0.8; }

/* nav toggle */
.navi-toggle {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 2rem;
  left: 2rem;
  position: fixed;
  top: 2rem;
  width: 3.6rem;
  z-index: 2; }
  .navi-toggle:hover {
    opacity: 0.8; }
  .navi-toggle .navi-toggle-bar,
  .navi-toggle .navi-toggle-bar::after,
  .navi-toggle .navi-toggle-bar::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    background: white;
    content: '';
    height: 0.4rem;
    width: 100%; }
  .navi-toggle .navi-toggle-bar {
    margin-top: 0; }
  .navi-toggle .navi-toggle-bar::after {
    margin-top: 0.8rem; }
  .navi-toggle .navi-toggle-bar::before {
    margin-top: -0.8rem; }
  .navi-toggle.expanded .navi-toggle-bar {
    background: transparent; }
  .navi-toggle.expanded .navi-toggle-bar::after, .navi-toggle.expanded .navi-toggle-bar::before {
    background: white;
    margin-top: 0; }
  .navi-toggle.expanded .navi-toggle-bar::after {
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg); }
  .navi-toggle.expanded .navi-toggle-bar::before {
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg); }

/* nav */
.navi {
  -webkit-transition: left 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: left 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: left 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: left 0.5s ease;
  transition: left 0.5s ease;
  background: #28dde0;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 2rem;
  height: 100vh;
  right: -30rem;
  padding: 6rem 2rem 2rem 2rem;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 20rem;
  z-index: 1; }
  .navi.expanded {
    left: 0; }
  .navi ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; }

/*# sourceMappingURL=nav.css.map */


/* NAVIGATION MENU */

div#main-menu {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
.btn-link {
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #007bff;
    background-color: transparent;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0;
}
ul.dropdown-list-item {
    padding: 0;
}
ul.dropdown-list-item li {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 100%;
}
ul.dropdown-list-item li a {
    font-size: 1rem;
}
.btn-link:hover{
  color: #fff;
}
/***  NAVIGATION ICONS   ***/
button.user-icon {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
}
.nav-icons {
    position: absolute;
    right: 13%;
    top: 23%;
}
/***  END NAVIGATION ICONS   ***/
```

```html
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<nav class="navi">

  <div id="main-menu">
    <div class="main-menu-list">
      <div class="main-menu-header" id="main-menu-one">
        <h5 class="mb-0">
          <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#dropdown-list-one" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="main-menu">Mens</button>
        </h5>
      </div>
      <div id="dropdown-list-one" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="main-menu-one" data-parent="#main-menu">
        <div class="dropdown-list-body">
          <ul class="dropdown-list-item">
            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

      <div class="main-menu-list">
        <div class="main-menu-header" id="main-menu-one">
          <h5 class="mb-0">
            <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#dropdown-list-two" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="main-menu">Womens</button>
          </h5>
        </div>
        <div id="dropdown-list-two" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="main-menu-one" data-parent="#main-menu">
          <div class="dropdown-list-body">
            <ul class="dropdown-list-item">
              <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

        <div class="main-menu-list">
          <div class="main-menu-header" id="main-menu-one">
            <h5 class="mb-0">
              <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#dropdown-list-three" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="main-menu">Accessories</button>
            </h5>
          </div>
          <div id="dropdown-list-three" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="main-menu-one" data-parent="#main-menu">
            <div class="dropdown-list-body">
              <ul class="dropdown-list-item">
                <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          </div>

          <div class="main-menu-list">
            <div class="main-menu-header" id="main-menu-one">
              <h5 class="mb-0">
                <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#dropdown-list-four" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="main-menu">Equipments</button>
              </h5>
            </div>
            <div id="dropdown-list-four" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="main-menu-one" data-parent="#main-menu">
              <div class="dropdown-list-body">
                <ul class="dropdown-list-item">
                  <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="main-menu-list">
              <div class="main-menu-header" id="main-menu-one">
                <h5 class="mb-0">
                  <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#dropdown-list-five" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="main-menu">More</button>
                </h5>
              </div>
              <div id="dropdown-list-five" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="main-menu-one" data-parent="#main-menu">
                <div class="dropdown-list-body">
                  <ul class="dropdown-list-item">
                    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
          </nav>
    
          <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-default fixed-top" id="nav">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="navi-toggle">
                <div class="navi-toggle-bar"></div>
              </div>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php"><img src="img/logo.png"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="container nav-icons">
             <button type="button" class="iconton">
              <img src="img/cart-product-white.png" alt="">
            </button> 
            <button type="button" class="iconton" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#userSearch" id="icon-search">
              <img src="img/navbar-icon.png">
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="iconton" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#userSign" id="icon-user">
              <img src="img/user.png">
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="container">

          </div>
        </nav>
```